# R Shiny: gvistable unable to call the selected row

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis, shinydashboard

I am trying to identify the selected rows in a gvistable used in a shiny dashboard. I have followed the steps prescribed by the demo (EventListener) but for some reason, I am unable to identify the selected row.

Here is a simplified and modified code to try and keep the question clear.

```
    library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
ui <- dashboardBody(box(title = "data table",width = 4, htmlOutput("dt")),
      verbatimTextOutput("row"))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  datatable <- data.frame("symbol" = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma"))

  output$dt <- renderGvis({
    d <- gvisTable(datatable, chartid = "mytable", options = list(gvis.listener.jscode= "
      var sel = chart.getSelected();
      var row = sel[0].row;
      var text = data.getValue(row,1);
      Shiny.onInputChange('text');
      "))
  })
  output$row <- renderPrint({
    input$text
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I always get NULL output on the `verbatimtextoutput`. Can anyone please point out the mistake I am making here?!
I tried numerous searches through the forums but could not find a solution.

Comment: Can you add link to the demo which you used?

Comment: sure.. it is `demo(EventListener)`

Answer (score 0):

I should maybe have not asked the question at all in the first place because the solution is very simple. But, maybe this will be useful for other users, its a cool option to have when you have other graphs or functions which use the objects in a gvistable as input. 
Here is the fix

```
d <- gvisTable(datatable, chartid = "mytable", options = list(gvis.listener.jscode = 
"var text = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row,0);
Shiny.onInputChange('text', text.toString());")
```

This makes the difference, Shiny.onInputChange takes two arguments and I had missed the second one.

Hope this helps other people trying something similar. 
BTW, another possible work around is using shinyjs. I will try that as well anyways.